# VB.net to SQL Server INSERT checkbox results

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, checkbox

I'm writing a VB.net program that records data in SQL Server 2012. At this stage I'm trying to create a new row in the database. The primary key automatically creates a line N+1, and to create the line you enter a new serial number. This all worked the other day, except you could not then load the row into the form to edit the rest of the data because it was tripping up on the nulls.

Anyway, I decided as I created the new row I'll load a blank space " " into all text boxes, today's date into all date boxes and a 'false' return on all check boxes. I've also added code to check for nulls. Below is the code to insert a result into the checkboxes, but I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near '='

My code:

```
Private Sub btnAddNewSerial_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click, btnAddNewSerial.Click
    Try
        con.ConnectionString = (frmAdmin.lblDBConnection.Text & frmAdmin.txtDBPW.Text & frmAdmin.lblDBConnection2.Text)
        con.Open()

        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO SLE1000DB (SK2SoakMainPCB) " & _
"VALUES (@SK2SoakMainPCB)”
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SK2SoakMainPCB", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = FrmSLE1000.chkSoakInteruptionsMainPCB.Checked

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()

        con.Close()

        MsgBox("Data updated")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error while inserting record on table..." & ex.Message, "Insert Records")
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try

    Me.Hide()
    frmSelect.Show()
End Sub
```

So if anyone can see whats causing the syntax error or can tell me a neater way of causing the checkbox to return a false result (I know that at the moment if it did work it would return a true result, that's something I'm still thinking about) Or just an overall neater way to achieve my goal that would be much appreciated. All my knowlage of VB.net and SQL Server comes from a book so is therefore, unfortunately, pretty limited!

The code presented here is just a snippet, there's actually an awful lot more columns that I'm passing data to, but I believe that its the checkboxes that are causing the syntax error as there aren't any "=" anywhere else in this bit of code and using a step through its this section that it gets caught up on.

Anyway thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you *try* debugging? Did you check where the error occurs?  Did you check the *actual error message*? You are calling `AddWithValue` and pass an **enumeration member** as the **value**. Enumerations are  stored as integers.  Then you try to set a *boolean* as the value of that **integer** property.

Comment: Did you notice that the closing double quote of your command text is not really a double quote?

Comment: That's not how you use `AddWithValue()`, the second parameter is supposed to be the value. But since you immediately overwrite it anyway that is not your actual problem, just an observation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub btnAddNewSerial_Click(sender As System.Object, e As 
System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click, btnAddNewSerial.Click
    Try

      con.ConnectionString = (frmAdmin.lblDBConnection.Text & 
frmAdmin.txtDBPW.Text & frmAdmin.lblDBConnection2.Text)
      con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO SLE1000DB (SK2SoakMainPCB) VALUES (@SK2SoakMainPCB)"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SK2SoakMainPCB",FrmSLE1000.chkSoakInteruptionsMainPCB.Checked)
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
          cmd.Parameters.Clear()
        con.Close()
        MsgBox("Data updated")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error while inserting record on table..." & ex.Message, "Insert Records")
    Finally
    con.Close()
    End Try

   Me.Hide()
  frmSelect.Show()
  End Sub
```

the add parameter with value was incorrect. For more info : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

hope this helps

Comment: The smart quote is still in there, and why do you think the call caused the syntax error? It *did* pass an **integer** as the value. Then it tried to **set** its value to a boolean. This won't raise a syntax error. This will result in a cast or runtime error

Comment: cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO SLE1000DB (SK2SoakMainPCB) VALUES (@SK2SoakMainPCB)" you misspelled the final quote.
as for the value being always true in the database the way you pas the parameter was incorrect .addwithvalue takes 2 argument : the name of the sql param and the actual value

Comment: As Steve posted in the *other* non-answer : `And do not post answers when there is a simple typo unlikeky to be repeated by anyone. Comments are enough`. There's a rule to **close** questions that only have a typo

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. Sapi- I cant see where the typo is??? I'm just going to check out your link now...

Comment: Also something went wrong when I entered my code snippet. the parameters line currently looks like this: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SK2SoakMainPCB", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = FrmSLE1000.chkSoakInteruptionsMainPCB.Checked

Comment: the typo is  cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO SLE1000DB (SK2SoakMainPCB) VALUES (@SK2SoakMainPCB)". at the end of the line its not a " you wrote. for your parameter try cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SK2SoakMainPCB", FrmSLE1000.chkSoakInteruptionsMainPCB.Checked) and let me know the result. Also if you use finally you dont need to close your connection in the try block :)

Comment: Hi Sapi, I tried your suggestion. in the Immediate window it says "A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll" and the Message that appears is "Error while inserting record on table... Incorrect Syntax near '='."

Comment: If its still saying that there's a syntax error near a '=' then it must be to do with the connections at the beginning as there are no '=' near the checkboxes now and the only other 3 '=' are in the connection set up at the beginning of the  Sub...

Comment: alright my best guess then is that your connextion string is malformed. either debugg step by step by placing a breakpoint on the  con.ConnectionString = (frmAdmin.lblDBConnection.Text & 
frmAdmin.txtDBPW.Text & frmAdmin.lblDBConnection2.Text) line or sipmky display frmAdmin.lblDBConnection.Text & 
frmAdmin.txtDBPW.Text & frmAdmin.lblDBConnection2.Text. Paste me the result

Comment: ok so, I ran the program with a breakpoint at the beginning of this bit of code (which is actually about 450 lines in real life) and I stepped though the whole thing. When it hits the first parameter involving the checkbox it runs some of the code in the FrmSLE1000 form and then comes back and its only when it gets to the line "Catch ex As Exception" that it then produces the error.

Comment: ohhh didnt realise your checkbox wasnt in your form. to get the value you need to get the current instance of the form where the checkbox is if it exist. i wont wont be able to help you much since i have no idea of your  program architecture.During debug you can display the values of the variables so you should first check that your connection string format is correct, then check if you can access the value of the checkbox(i doubt it)